# Replace default react-native-render-html components with custom ones

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-native-render-html

I need to somehow replace the defualt components with my own. For example: The renderer needs to render  from react-native, but I want to somehow set it to render  from native-base library. Is something like this possible? All I've read so far is just styling the components, but not replacing them with custom ones.

input: `<p>text</p>`

What I DON'T want:

```
<Text>text</Text>
```

What I need:

```
<CustomComponent>text</CustomComponent>
```